# udevadm monitor parsing output for timestamp

Tags: python, udev

I am logging `udevadm monitor` output and want to print the datetime of the event.

Here is a line from that log.

```
  UDEV  [529296.231213] remove   /devices/virtual/input/input46 (input)
```

And from the udevadm man page:

```
  udevadm monitor [options]
     Listens to the kernel uevents and events sent out by a udev rule and prints the devpath of the event to the console. It can be used to analyze the event timing, by comparing the timestamps of the kernel uevent and the udev event.
```

How can I translate that timestamp 529296.231213 to actual datetime. Parsing with Python:

```
timestamp = 529296.231213
dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
```

produces `1986-06-12 11:51:36.231213` whereas now is late afternoon 2023-04-27.

Comment: That number (`529296.231213`)
 is not a date/time, it is the _seconds_._nanoseconds_ since boot - the system uptime.

Comment: @waltinator So I add that number of seconds to the time of the first entry in the boot journal . Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Only if your log is well-behaved, and the first entry has a `[000000.000000]` "since boot" offset.